# Fetch data from google spreadsheet in magento 2

Tags: magento2, google

I want to fetch the data from one column of the google spreadsheet and display the data on the CMS page in magento 2.
Is there any way to do this?
Any customization or any extension?
Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, For that You have to pull the required dependencies which is required to communicate with google api to read and write data.

```
composer require google/apiclient:^2.0
```

I am sharing the below reference link which help us to use the google spreadsheets data to our php script.

[Integrating Google Sheets With PHP is This Easy- Know How!](https://www.srijan.net/resources/blog/integrating-google-sheets-with-php-is-this-easy-know-how)

After that you can just replace the functions according to your magento controllers or Blocks.